# I get different outputs when i use different compilers

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, gcc, clang

I was trying to solve a problem with using C. But I got different outputs in different compilers. First I tried gcc and there was no mistake but when I use clang the output changed.

PROBLEM:
Given five positive integers, find the minimum and maximum values that can be calculated by summing exactly four of the five integers. Then print the respective minimum and maximum values as a single line of two space-separated long integers.

Sample Input: `1 2 3 4 5`

Sample Output: `10 14`

10 = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 | 14 = 2 + 3 + + 4 + 5

The Output when I use clang: `1 14`

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void  miniMaxSum(int *a, int b) {

    int sums[5] = { b, b, b, b, b };
    int min = *a, max = *a;
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        sums[j] -= *(a + j);
        if (sums[j] < min)
            min = sums[j];
        if (toplamlar[j] > max)
            max = sums[j];
    }

    printf("%d %d\n", min, max);
}

int main() {

    int numbers[5] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    int sum;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        scanf("%d ", &numbers[i]);
        toplam += numbers[i];
    }

    miniMaxSum(numbers, sum);

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**: Sorry, I changed the variables name to English sake of understanding, but I forgot the `toplam` (`sum`) and `toplamlar` (`sums`).

Comment: What is toplam?!

Comment: Where is `toplam` , `toplamlar[]`, defined.  Best to post a [mcve].

Comment: I would be surprised if any of the compilers that you tested actually compiled this code.

Comment: Getting different results is a common symptom of code that has undefined or implementation-dependent behavior.

Comment: @Talha Arda BÜLBÜL The variable sum is uninitialized.

Comment: The space after `"%d "` in `scanf("%d ", &numbers[i]);` is likely causing issues.  Best to delete it.

Comment: It looks like you tried to translate your variable names to English, but missed a few places.

Comment: That title should be added to the standard definition of undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you translated some of the variable names to English for non Turkish speakers, the variable `sum` (`toplam`) is uninitialized leading to undefined behavor.  A common symptom for undefined behavior is different behavior on a different system / compiler.

Note that you can simplify your code by just searching for the minimum and maximum values in the array:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void miniMaxSum(const int *a, int sum) {
    int min = a[0], max = a[0];
    for (int j = 1; j < 5; j++) {
        if (sums[j] < min)
            min = sums[j];
        if (sums[j] > max)
            max = sums[j];
    }
    printf("%d %d\n", sum - max, sum - min);
}

int main() {
    int numbers[5] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        scanf("%d ", &numbers[i]);
        sum += numbers[i];
    }

    miniMaxSum(numbers, sum);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @TalhaArdaBÜLBÜL: you can accept the answer by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score. Clicking twice unaccepts the answer, which might not be your intent.